# Which source gave the option for a spellcaster to use wishes as verbal component?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, spellcasting, content-identification

I vaguely remember that I have seen a Dungeons and Dragons subclass, variant or feat that allowed a spellcaster who studied Genies or was related to them to cast spells by using spoken wishes as verbal component, instead of speaking themself.

I would like to update it to 5e, because I really like the concept, but first I need to find the original material.

I *suspect* it was 3.5 material, but I'm really not sure. It could be an internet material, friend's book, or magazine in a game shop, I honestly can't remember. **What source is this feature from?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may be thinking of the [Wishcrafter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit/wishcrafter-sorcerer-ifrit/) archetype for the Sorcerer class from Pathfinder 1e (similar enough to 3.5 that it could fit the bill). The archetype is for ifrit only, a race descended from efreeti (as aasimar and tieflings are from celestials and fiends).

At first level, instead of receiving a bloodline arcana like a typical sorcerer, a Wishcrafter can replace verbal components with another creature's spoken wish for a variety of benefits.

Comment: You mean this one? https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit/wishcrafter-sorcerer-ifrit/ - as far as I can tell, the resource is legal, so you may link it in your answer, if that's indeed it. You got +1 from me, and I need to think hard if that's really it before I'll accept your answer, but it very well may be.

Comment: @Mołot Yes, d20pfsrd.com is legally using licensed open game content that Paizo has made available under the OGL. Basically all mechanical Pathfinder material is open. Linking to it is acceptable here.